# Install an alternative OS to Windows CE

Tags: netbook, software-rec, windows-ce

I've an EASY PC E700 WinCE Series. 
Windows CE 6.0 is installed on it, but it's very awful! 
It doesn't let me see videos on Youtube and Adobe Flash can't be installed.

I surfed the Web to search an alternate OS (I also searched for another web browser, and I found Opera Mini, but it's the same installed on phones, so it's not so good for netbooks), but I don't understand if Debian (or other Linux based OSs) can be installed on this machine.

This is its hw (if you can call it so):

- CPU: VIA WM VT8500 ( ARM 926EJ-S )
- RAM: 128MB DDR2
- 2GB NAND FLASH

According to [this answer](http://lists.debian.org/debian-arm/2010/10/msg00053.html) it can't be installed, but it seems Android can. Unluckily I've not found a valid "document" explaining how to install it. I've found only a tutorial about [easy_linux](http://tails92.sepwich.com/easypc_linux/), but the same developer says it's bugged.

What do you suggest me?
Ok, as well as throwing it out the window! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, your machine might indeed be able to run some flavor of Linux. Here are my comments on this though :

- It is very, very likely that getting a proper Linux environment to run on the thing will take you a huge amount of time
- Hardware support on Linux might not be very good (for instance some peripherals might not work)
- The computing power of this device is very, very low. No matter the software, the hardware is not powerful enough to stream YouTube videos.

With all this in mind, I think the most efficient solution for you would be to buy a cheap (but recent) Atom-based, Ubuntu-supported Netbook.

Comment: ... unless you want to learn a lot about computers. Getting Linux working on this puppy will involve becoming quite expert--you might even have to write your own device drivers.

Comment: I was afraid of an answer like this. That's the truth, though. Thank you!